# Why is this file not writing?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, embedded, embedded-linux

So I have a situation where I am trying to write to an Embedded Linux file (Nitrogen6x board).  I can do this manually with `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value`.  However, when I try and do this same thing via C code:

```
FILE *fs;
fs = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value","w")
fputc(1,fs);
fclose(fs);
```

it doesn't work.  It doesn't give any errors or anything, it just doesn't work.  Has anyone ever encountered this before?  What can I do to fix this.  Is there a way to "echo" like I do manually...but do this from code?  What is the best way to proceed?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Are you writing in binary or text mode?  Your fputc is outputting a non-printable value.

Comment: First thing to do is make sure that `fs` is not `NULL` - in other words, were you able to open the file successfully?

Comment: For starters, its `FILE*`, not `FILE`. I'm shocked this compiled.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig That IS what I had in my code so I edited it to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe if you had looked at the size of the file after the write....

Comment: The `fopen()` and `FILE*` infrastructure buffer data.  You should call `fflush()` to ensure the data gets sent to the kernel before closing **or** use `open()` and regular `int fd` **or** call `system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value");`.  Definitely ensure you have a `\n` newline as per Mats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you are writing "CTRL-A" (character code 1, not the digit '1' that echo sends) to the gpio16/value.

Try:

```
fputc('1', fs);
```

If that still doesn't work, it may be that you need a newline as well:

```
fputs("1\n", fs);
```

Comment: Mats - you are writing a string, not a character?

Comment: Yes, typo, fixed by @corduro.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean (and did you try the FIXED version or the broken one that I originally posted?)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Ok I just tried this new one and it went!  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MatsPetersson What if I wanted to do it with a variable instead of '1'?  what would it look like?  `fputc(one, fs);`?

Comment: I would guess that using `fprintf(fs, "%d\n", some_variable_or_calculation);` would be your best choice.

Comment: I suspect the `fputc('1', fs);` would work if followed by fflush(fs);

Answer (score 3):

Try using `fputc('1',fs);`.

`echo` writes asci that you redirect to the file.